# Detect browser opening new tab by an application or by user using c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, process, windows

I want to detect if the new tab is being opened by an application. I have written some code that get the parent process id. The main idea is that a service will contentiously monitor the default browser's(Here is Chrome) PID(Process ID) values if it changes it will look for the parent's pid whether it is created by the user or by an application. For the user the pid will reffer explorer.exe and for the application it will be another. This code works fine when user has not started the browser yet and if some application tries to open a url in the browser.

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    private static string FindIndexedProcessName(int pid)
    {
        var processName = Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName;
        var processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        string processIndexdName = null;

        for (var index = 0; index < processesByName.Length; index++)
        {
            processIndexdName = index == 0 ? processName : processName + "#" + index;
            var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);
            if ((int)processId.NextValue() == pid)
            {
                return processIndexdName;
            }
        }

        return processIndexdName;
    }

    private static Process FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(string indexedProcessName)
    {
        var parentId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", indexedProcessName);
        return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId.NextValue());
    }

    public static Process Parent(this Process process)
    {
        return FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(FindIndexedProcessName(process.Id));
    }
}
```

usage

```
MessageBox.Show("ParentPid: " + Process.GetProcessById(pid_value).Parent().Id);
```

**Problem Arises(Tested for chrome)**
When the user already opens the browser and then the application try to open new tab.My application then detect the parent pid as explorer.exe not the application that opens the browser. so is there a way to detect that. I know this can be achieved by a system level hook but i need an easy way. please help me. Thank you.

Comment: FYI: PerformanceCounter is an IDisposable...

Comment: hi @elgonzo thanks for your comment ya you are right but my code works fine but not fully i think that new process is crating for chrome from its previous process so how can i achieve it any idea? Thank you.